# Firebird 2.5 CHARACTER SET WIN1252 is not installed

Tags: firebird, freebsd, firebird2.5

I've installed Firebird-Server 2.5 on FreeBsd 9.1 using:

```
pkg install firebird-server-2.5.2_1
```

It's working ok, since I can connect using FlameRobin from an external PC.

Now, when I try to restore a database using gbak, I got this:

```
...
gbak: ERROR:    CHARACTER SET WIN1252 is not installed
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors
```

Should I install something more server side?. The database was created on a Windows machine, that's why its character set is WIN1252.

EDIT: after some trouble I deinstalled firebird and reinstalled WITHOUT USING SUDO.

Now I can connect using isql-fb and do "show system collation;". Here's the result:

```
...
TIS620_UNICODE, CHARACTER SET TIS620, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
UCS_BASIC, CHARACTER SET UTF8, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
UNICODE, CHARACTER SET UTF8, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
UNICODE_CI, CHARACTER SET UTF8, FROM EXTERNAL ('UNICODE'), PAD SPACE, CASE INSENSITIVE, SYSTEM
UNICODE_CI_AI, CHARACTER SET UTF8, FROM EXTERNAL ('UNICODE'), PAD SPACE, CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT   INSENSITIVE, SYSTEM
UNICODE_FSS, CHARACTER SET UNICODE_FSS, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
UTF8, CHARACTER SET UTF8, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1250, CHARACTER SET WIN1250, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1251, CHARACTER SET WIN1251, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1251_UA, CHARACTER SET WIN1251, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1252, CHARACTER SET WIN1252, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1253, CHARACTER SET WIN1253, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1254, CHARACTER SET WIN1254, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1255, CHARACTER SET WIN1255, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1256, CHARACTER SET WIN1256, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1257, CHARACTER SET WIN1257, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1257_EE, CHARACTER SET WIN1257, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1257_LT, CHARACTER SET WIN1257, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1257_LV, CHARACTER SET WIN1257, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN1258, CHARACTER SET WIN1258, PAD SPACE, SYSTEM
WIN_CZ, CHARACTER SET WIN1250, PAD SPACE, CASE INSENSITIVE, SYSTEM
WIN_CZ_CI_AI, CHARACTER SET WIN1250, PAD SPACE, CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT INSENSITIVE, SYSTEM
WIN_PTBR, CHARACTER SET WIN1252, PAD SPACE, CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT INSENSITIVE, SYSTEM
```

...but using gbak I still get the same error.

Comment: What do you see when you run `show system collation;` in ISQL?

Comment: It asks me to connect to a database. Then, when I try to connect, I get "Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000
Can't access lock files' directory /tmp/firebird"

Comment: Make sure to prefix `localhost:` before the database name.

Comment: Now I get: "cannot attach to password database". Password database is in /var/db/firebird/security2.fdb owned by firebird:firebird, permissions -rw-rw----

Comment: Sounds like your Firebird server isn't running with the right privileges

Comment: Please, read the EDIT I posted.

Answer (score 8):

You have no access to **intl** subfolder. Few reasons:

- You dont have right to access it ( mostly on linux/unix OS )
- using embedded **fbembed.dll** without copy of **intl** subfolder
- something wrong with your path, and Firebird fails to find **intl** subfolder

Most of these causes can be fixed by simple reinstalling server. If it's embedded , then you only need to copy **intl** folder , where **fbembed.dll** exists

Comment: thanks a lot , i am not sure but i think that intl content have to be in the same level as embedded..dll

Answer (score 0):

Seems that was an issue with ICU with new port update it should be fixed

http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports?view=revision&revision=328894

You can check other changes here

http://www.freshports.org/databases/firebird25-server/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my firebird-super-server was working fine, until I have upgraded packages in my CentOS 7. Then I get an error mentioned below.

ERROR MSG ->

> Firebird 2.5 CHARACTER SET WIN1250 is not installed

**Solution**  : After Changing firebird-super-server to firebird-super-classic resolved my problem.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the package that you should report to the maintainer of the CentOS port of Firebird.

Comment: The same happens here. Don't they try these themselves before pushing these packages into mirrors? It's not like this would be used something fun, this broke my bookkeeping software.

Comment: Downgrading helped to that error, get packages from https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=860631

Comment: Also put exclude=firebird-filesystem,firebird-superserver,firebird,firebird-libfbembed,firebird-libfbclient   (and others) to /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo