# Firedac connection error to firebird 2.1 with character set xxx

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio, firebird2.1

I try to connect with firedac to firebird 2.1 character set ISO8859_1 with Delphi 10.3 Rio. Connection is ok if I use embedded fb in work directory. If there is no embedded fb and firebird server is stopped, it still connect but with : Error is character set ISO8859_1 is not defined.

How to find where are that embedded fb, which Delphi 10.3 Rio connect?

Comment: Does your Firebird install have a `intl` folder and `intl/fbintl.conf` and `intl/fbintl.dll` (or `intl/fbintl.so` for Linux)?

Comment: Related, probably duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354240/firebird-2-5-character-set-win1252-is-not-installed

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my Firebird install have a `intl` folder and `intl/fbintl`.conf and `intl/fbintl.dll`

Comment: Could you check table `RDB$CHARACTER_SETS` if `ISO8859_1` exists? If not, try backing up and restoring your database. Also, are you sure you are connecting to the server (and not accidentally using an incomplete Firebird Embedded instead).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel See additional information on my question...

Comment: If you stopped the server and it can still connect, then you do have an incomplete Firebird Embedded that is used by your application. Make sure that your connection properties also specify a hostname. You could use tools like procmon to see which dlls are loaded.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel when I specify hostname localhost then works fine

Comment: Then I suggest you use that as the solution.